# Google Maps Api : 20 results with nearbySearch() but only 9 with PlacesService()

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps Api, and here is what I do :

- I initialize the map
- I search restaurants with [nearbySearch()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests). The API gives me 20 results.
- I need comments and ratings details, so I search details with [getDetails()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details) for each of the 20 previous results. But the API only gives me 9 results...

I'm only using example from the documentation... so I don't understand why it does that !

Here is my code : (look at the console, nothing will appear on the map, that's normal)

```js
var map;
var service;

// MapInit()
function MapInit() {

    // Initial position, the problem doesn't come from the location, you can test
    var initialPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(48.8589507, 2.2770201); // Paris
    //var initialPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6976701, -74.2598681); // New York
    //var initialPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(35.6735408, 139.5703028); // Tokyo

    // I create the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: initialPosition,
        zoom: 15
    });

    // I prepare the request for nearbySearch()
    var request = {
        location: initialPosition,
        radius: '1000',
        types: ['restaurant']
    };

    // I do the nearbySearch() request to found restaurants around the initial position
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, NearbySearchCallback);

}


// This function is called when nearbySearch() has done
function NearbySearchCallback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        // 20 results for this search
        console.log("### All results for nearbySearch() ###");
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log(results[i].name);
        }

        // I do a new search for the details with getDetails(), but it will only return me 9 results instead of 20
        console.log("### All results for getDetails() ###");

        // For each results of the nearbySearch() request
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            // I prepare the request for getDetails()
            var place = results[i];
            var request = {
                placeId: place.place_id
            };

            // I do the getDetails() request for each results
            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.getDetails(request, getDetailsCallback);
        }
    }
}

// This function is called when getDetails() has done
function getDetailsCallback(place, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.log(place.name);
    }
}
```

Here is the console.log :

```
### All results for nearbySearch() ###
Maison FL
Ken Club
Sushi Gourmet
La Gare
Astrance
Café Kléber
Restaurant Bon
LE FRANKLIN Passy
Café de l'Homme
Sushi Shop Mozart
Café du Trocadéro
Château de la Tour
Le Grand Bistro de la Muette
Matsuri Passy
Pizza Hut Annonciation
Domino's Pizza Paris 16 Nord
Le Relais du Bois
Family Café
Settebello
Genio
### All results for getDetails() ###
Astrance
Ken Club
LE FRANKLIN Passy
Sushi Gourmet
La Gare
Restaurant Bon
Café de l'Homme
Maison FL
Café Kléber
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I'm on it since 2 days and I still don't understand what's happening.

If my code completly is wrong, the main question I have is : **how can I get the comments and ratings from the 20 results ?**

Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Google's services are subject to both a rate limit and a quota.  The rate limting limits you to about 10 results, before enforcing the long term limit (~1 per second).  Check the `status` in the response (you are currently silently ignoring failures), if it is `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` you need to slow down your requests.  If you do the details request on a user action (like a click on a marker or a link, you won't have this issue).